# Explicitly calling garbage collection in .NET

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

My understanding is that in Java, if I explicitly call for a garbage collection, all that call does is "hint" to the garbage collector that a collection has been requested.

Based on reading the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y46kxc5e(v=vs.110).aspx am I right in saying this is NOT the case in .NET, and that if I call for a garbage collection, then a garbage collection is run?

The documentation says the following:

> Use this method to try to reclaim memory that is inaccessible. However, using this method does not guarantee that all inaccessible memory in the specified generation is reclaimed.
>   If object aging is implemented, the garbage collector does not collect objects with a generation number that is higher than the specified generation. If object aging is not implemented, the garbage collector considers all objects during the garbage collection.

Now that to me, implies that the garbage collector runs when you make a call to it - or am I reading it wrong?

If it is just a hint, how do memory profilers work for instance?

Everybody I have asked has told me it is a **hint** only in .NET also, so if this not the case now, has it ever been the case in previous .NET versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you trigger the GC.

[`GCCollectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495757.aspx):

> `Default` The default setting for this enumeration, which is currently Forced.
>
> `Forced`  Forces the garbage collection to occur immediately.
>
> `Optimized`   Allows the garbage collector to determine whether the current time is optimal to reclaim objects.

If you call the parameterless overload or pass `GCCollectionMode.Default` it currently forces a GC, but in theory that behaviour may change in future versions of .NET.

If you pass `GCCollectionMode.Forced` it forces an immediate GC.

If you pass `GCCollectionMode.Optimized` it's only a hint. I don't know how seriously the runtime treats this hint.

So if you want to either force a GC or make sure that it's only a hint, use the [`Collect(int generation, GCCollectionMode mode)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356724.aspx) overload.

Answer (score 3):

"Object aging" is a clumsy way to say that the garbage collector supports multiple generations.  For example, the desktop version of .NET uses 3 generations, the Compact Framework uses only 1 generation.  It is a CLR implementation detail.  As objects "age", in other words live longer and survive collections, they'll move into a higher-numbered generation.  It is an optimization, the GC will do less work on objects that are unlikely to need to be collected.

So in the case of CF, no matter what you pass as the argument, the entire heap is collected.  In the desktop version, the generations equal to the argument as well as the younger generations get collected.  In other words, GC.Collect(1) will collect gen #0 and gen #1 and not do anything at all with gen #2.

Comment: I wonder how hard it would have been to make the CF support generational GC for sealed classes with no reference-type fields [all mutable objects would be stuck at level 0]?  The benefits wouldn't be as great as would be possible if reference-holding objects could promote, or if there were a way the GC could know that a reference-holding object was immutable, but I think some reasonable benefits could be had relatively cheaply.